# Rescue "undefined method 'xyz' for nil:nilClass" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following show action:

```
def show
  @name = params[:id]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to :action => 'index'     
  @rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name(@name, :include => :rpm_comments)
  @page_title = @rpm.name
end
```

Even though I've added a rescue statement there, it doesn't seem to work and I get this error when I try to view a non existent URL:

`undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

I know that this might be related to the `@page_title` variable, but how can I fix this?

Comment: First of all, your `rescue` statement is in the wrong place, it should come AFTER the exception could be raised. And secondly, none of your code raises any exceptions, `find_by_name` returns nil, perhaps you want `find_by_name!` which raises instead. Your redirect is also half way through your action, it's very confusing to work out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this: I'm trying to redirect to the index action when the RPM is not found by name in the FedoraRpm model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name(@name, :include => :rpm_comments)
```

returns nil if unable to find a result. This is probably your case. Then, you attempts to invoke `name` on a nil object.

If you expect the query to return a nil value, make sure to change your code accordingly.

The rescue statement doesn't make any sense there. If you want to redirect in case of missing record when use

```
def show
  @name = params[:id]
  @rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name!(@name, :include => :rpm_comments)
  @page_title = @rpm.name
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to :action => 'index'     
end
```

Note I used the bang version of the finder.

```
@rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name!(@name, :include => :rpm_comments)
```

Comment: How do I redirect to the index action if it returns nil?

Comment: Oh, I don't think you understood my problem. Sorry for not being clear...Doing that simply redirects all URLs to the index controller. I am rendering individual pages for the *existing* RPMs through this code in the view, however, I need to redirect the URLs for the *non-existing* RPMs to the index action....

Comment: If it redirects all the URLs is because all the URLs return a missing record. You should check the query in your console and make sure it works as expected.

Comment: okay, sorry, just double checked that; thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Can I also pass the incorrect part of the URL as a parameter if I'm redirecting to a not_found action; so that I'm able to display 'Did you mean' suggestion on that page?

Comment: OMG. I have been having this problem and the magic ! just fixed it. Now instead of an ugly undefined method on nil error and an email, my rescue from not found is kicking in. So glad I found this answer. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you do. There are 2 reasons:

1. The rescue statement you use is before the place where error happens, or could happen
2. You point to special type of error **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** that wil be fired only when you use **find** method, or adding ! at the end of **find_by_name**

So you should move rescue line to the bottom of the method, like:

```
def show
  @name = params[:id]
  @rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name!(@name, :include => :rpm_comments)
  @page_title = @rpm.name
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to :action => 'index'     
end
```

Notice I`ve added ! mark to the end of find_by_name, it will fire an exception of record is not found, in your case it would just return **nil**, so you would hace error when trying to get .name from nil

Comment: doing that still returns the  "undefined method 'name' for nil:nilClass" error...